# prime ideal that is not max ideal

Tags: ideals

It's easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian but not artinian.
In my course notes there's proven:
$A$ a commutative ring: $A$ artininian $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ noetherian and Spec($A$) = Max($A$)

with Spec($A$) = collection of prime ideals,

so there must be a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ that is not maximal. Can someone give me an example of this?

Comment: Hint: It is trivial.

Comment: aah, the trivial ideal, thanks